# Term reference field - print as other format

Tags: theming, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I'm using term reference field, which is displaying as entity.

I want to print this in the other place of node.tpl, not full entity but only names.

Is this possible?

I've tried

```
<?php print render($content['event_speakers']['und'][0]['value']); ?>
```

But it doesn't print anything

Comment: use dpm($content) in your file then check which value you want to display add this field in your file

Comment: It just shows field collection item #markup with code from my .tpl file, with names already printed.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I didn't completely get your question initially. To do this you will need to fetch the term names yourself, and make them available to your node template file. This means you'll have to use `hook_preprocess_node()` implementation.

Here's the code you'd use:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->type == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE' && isset($variables['node']->field_event_speakers[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'])) {
    $event_speakers = array();
    foreach ($variables['node']->field_event_speakers[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $event_speaker) {
      $term = taxonomy_term_load($event_speakers['tid']);
      // Just to display the name:
      $event_speakers[] = $term->name;
      // To display linked name instead, use this:
      // $event_speakers[] = l($term->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid);
    }
    // This will separate names with a comma, and a space.
    $variables['event_speakers'] = implode(', ', $event_speakers);
  }
}
```

You can then use this as many times as you want in the template; example:

```
<div class="speakers-top"><?php print $event_speakers; ?></div>
<div class="speakers-bottom"><?php print $event_speakers; ?></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't print anything sir :(

Comment: My bad; you need to pass different argument to the `render()` function; check the code now, I updated the answer.

Comment: It's printing the whole term reference entity. I just need the names of it.

Comment: Updated. I think I got what you were asking for now.